# can we use sql compact edition data base for multiple system network access

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce

Hi now we are using sql compact edition database for windows forms in .net..and i am using data base for multiple systems by sharing but while using it....it is showing an error that already another process is using it...so can u please fix the problem and tell me there is any solution to solve this problem....thaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Compact only supports connections from a single machine, so no network access allowed, for this requirement you should use SQL Server Express.